# Efeito deslizante em links 'ancora'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, link, css-transições

Tenho uma página **OnePage** e os links ancora dos menus quando clicados eles apenas "**saltam**" para a secção da tela mais abaixo, mas eu queria que eles **deslizassem** com suavidade até a secção 'ancora' destinada.

Tentei colocar o `transition` via CSS e não tive sucesso, não sei se não tem como fazer isso via CSS, ou se eu estou colocando a classe com o `transition` no lugar errado.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a href="#contact" style="transition: all .25s linear;">Contato</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: quando clicar no link Contato, a página vai rolar para baixo e você quer o efeito do transition ?

Comment: Sim. Porque quando eu clico no contato eu queria que ele rolasse a página até o contato, não que ele fosse instantaneamente para o contato. Queria esse efeito, um delay. Acredito que dê para fazer com CSS, mas eu não consegui.

Comment: @ThiagoFriedman Caso prefira eu pego um exemplo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Infelizmente isto não é possível de ser feito usando CSS, para alcançar este efeito pretendido terás que usar Javascript/jQuery.

Eis um exemplo abaixo de como podes fazer isto utilizando jQuery, e também tens aqui um <kbd>**[EXEMPLO AO VIVO NO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/furh0pds/)**</kbd>.

Bom, primeiro para que o código jQuery abaixo funcione é necessário implementar a Biblioteca jQuery, antes do encerramento da tag `</head>` do teu site (**caso não a tenhas já implementada**).
Para isso isso tens que adicionar a seguinte linha de código:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Depois podes então inserir o código jQuery que irá tratar do efeito de scroll suave para o link ancora, que também pode ser implementado logo em seguida a esta linha de código acima.
Tudo junto ficará assim:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var $doc = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
    $doc.animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

> **Nota:** O código jQuery acima foi criado apontando para a tag `<a>`, mas
>   o recomendado seria criar uma `class` especifica apenas para lidar
>   com isto, como por exemplo `class="scrollSuave"` e adicionar esta
>   class aos links que queres que este efeito seja aplicado, por exemplo:
>
> ```
> <a href="#contact" class="scrollSuave">Contato</a>
> <a href="#about" class="scrollSuave">Contato</a>
> etc ...
> ```
>
> E claro, também fazer esta modificação no código jQuery apontando-o agora para a `class="scrollSuave"` nesta linha:
>
> ```
> $('.scrollSuave').click(function() {
> ```
>
> Desta forma estamos a apontar apenas este script para os links que queremos que o efeito seja aplicado e não para todos os links `<a>`.
>
> Aqui tens um link com um exemplo: **http://jsfiddle.net/qss4y1oe**

Answer (score 2):

Faço usando jQuery

```
var top = $('#contato').offset.top();

$(window).animation({
    scrollTop: top, // Separa condições.
}, 300);
```

Comment: Acho assim mais fácil, porém jquery só suporta o último navegador e o penúltimo, certo?

Comment: @MarceloRafael errado. Leia a documentação.