# Quando inserido conteúdo dentro da div, a página não rola certo

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Quando inserido conteúdo dentro da div, a página não rola certo, mas sem o conteúdo ela estava normal.

```js
    var _AlturaDocumento = $(window).height();
    function AlturaSecao(){
    $('.secao').height(_AlturaDocumento);
    }
    
    
    function ScrollSecao(){
    console.log('entrou');
    var body = $('html, body');
    if($(this).parent('.secao').is('#secao01')){
    body.animate({scrollTop: _AlturaDocumento}, '500');
    } else if($(this).parent('.secao').is('#secao02')){
    body.animate({scrollTop: _AlturaDocumento*2}, '500');
    }else if($(this).parent('.secao').is('#secao03')){
    body.animate({scrollTop: _AlturaDocumento*3}, '500');
    }
    else if($(this).parent('.secao').is('#secao04')){
    body.animate({scrollTop: _AlturaDocumento*4}, '500');
    }else {
     body.animate({scrollTop: 0}, '800');
    }
    }
    
    $('.icone-scroll').click(ScrollSecao);
    
     
    $(AlturaSecao);
```

```css
  <style>
      body{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      }
      
      p{
      position:absolute;
      top:80px;
      left:5px;
      }
      
      h1{
      position:absolute;
      top:10px;
      left:5px;
      }
      
      h2{
      position:absolute;
      top:10px;
      left:5px;
      }
      .secao{
      position:relative;
      }
      
      #secao01{
      background-color:#0B77C5;
      width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 180px;
    padding: 1px 0;
      }
      
      #secao02{
      background-color:#fff;
      width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 180px;
    padding: 1px 0;
      }
      
      #secao03{
      background-color:#000;
      color:#fff;
      width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1px 0;
      }
      
      #secao04{
      background-color:#ccc;
      width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1px 0;
      }
       #secao05{
      background-color:#FFF;
      width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1px 0;
      }
      
     .icone-scroll{
      position:absolute;
      bottom:3em;
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      background-color:#1a1a1a;
      border-radius: 50%;
      left:50%;
      margin-left:-25px;
      cursor:pointer;
      }
      
      .scroll{
      width:15px;
      height:15px;
      border-right: 2px solid #fff;
      border-bottom : 2px solid #fff;
      display:inline-block;
      position:relative;
      }
      
      .scroll-next{
      transform:rotate(45deg);
      margin:14px 0 0 16.5px;
      }
      
      .scroll-top{
      transform:rotate(225deg);
      margin:19px 0 0 17px;
      }
      
      .scroll-top + .scroll-top{
      top:-15px;
      margin-top:0;
      }
      </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--TESTE CLIQUE DIV -->
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>CURRICULUM</title>
    <body>
      <div id="secao01" class="secao"> 
    <h1>
    <center><b>
    
    Nome Completo</b></center> </h1>
    <br>
    <p>
    
     
     RUA, Numero - Bairro<br> Cidade/Estado, Cep<br>
    CELULAR: 11980****** <br>
    E-MAIL: KINHO.***********@GMAIL.COM
      </p>  
      <span class="icone-scroll">
      
      <span class ="scroll-next scroll"> </span>
      </span>
      
      </div>
      
      
      <div id="secao02" class="secao">
      <h3>EDUCAÇÃO E FORMAÇÃO</h3>
      <p> 
      ANÁLISE E DESENVOLVIMENTO DE SISTEMAS - ANHANGUERA
             INÍCIO: JAN/2019 - TÉRMINO: JUN/2021<br>
    
    TÉCNICO EM INFORMÁTICA (PROGRAMAÇÃO) - INSTITUTO TÉCNICO DE BARUERI
              INÍCIO: JUL/2015 - TÉRMINO: JUL/2017<br>
    
    ENSINO MÉDIO COMPLETO (EJA) - E.E. MARIA ALICE CRISSIUMA MESQUITA
              TÉRMINO: DEZ/2014 </p>
      <span class="icone-scroll">
      <span class ="scroll-next scroll"> </span>
      </span>
      
      </div>
      
      
      <div id="secao03" class="secao"> 
      
      <h2>EXPERIÊNCIA PROFISSIONAL </h2>
       <p> 
      HIBERO EXTINTORES, CARAPICUÍBA - SP<br>
     CARGO: PINTOR<br>
     INÍCIO: SET/2011<br>
              TÉRMINO: MAI/2019 </p>
      <span class="icone-scroll">
      <span class ="scroll-next scroll"> </span>
      </span>
      </div>
      
      
      
      <div id="secao04" class="secao"> 
      
      <h2> QUALIFICAÇÕES E ATIVIDADES PROFISSIONAIS</h2>
        
    <p> C#, JAVA, HTML5, ASP.NET, ECLIPSE ANDROID, ORACLE SQL</p>
      <span class="icone-scroll">
      <span class ="scroll-next scroll"> </span>
      </span>
      </div>
      
      <div id="secao05" class="secao"> 
       <h2>OBJETIVO </h2>
      <p> ESTÁGIO/TRAINEE EM DESENVOLVIMENTO DE SISTEMAS </p>
      <span class="icone-scroll">
      <span class ="scroll-top scroll"> </span>
      </span>
      
      </div>
      
      
      </body>
      
    
      
 
    </html>
```

Comment: Editei sua pergunta para o código ser executável e não vi problema nenhum. Pode Executá-lo e ser mais específico no seu problema?

Comment: Cara mas a forma como vc está calculando não é legal.... esses `_AlturaDocumento*1` ou `_AlturaDocumento*2`... quem te garante que realmente essa conta vai bater com o tamanho do conteúdo? A section 2 pode ter 3* a altura, ai sua lógica vai pro saco... Veja outras formas de fazer aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90119/efeito-deslizante-em-links-ancora

Comment: Peguei em um exemplo de site, então, achei que não teria esse problema do ajuste ao conteúdo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa pegar a altura do `window` para fazer isso. Basta colocar no CSS, na classe `.secao`, a propriedade `height: 100vh;` para que as divs tenham sempre a altura da janela.

```
.secao{
   position:relative;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

E remova todos os `height` dos id's `#secao01` a `#secao05`.

Quanto ao código jQuery, está muito complicado quando você pode fazer de uma forma muito mais simples, movendo o scroll para a div posterior ao do ícone clicado, sem precisar fazer multiplicação. Veja no exemplo que não precisa de muita coisa que você colocou, basta um `if...else`:

```js
$(function(){

   function ScrollSecao(){
     // console.log('entrou');
      var body = $('html, body');
      
      var secao = $(this).parent(".secao").next().offset().top;
      
      if($(this).parent('.secao').is('#secao05')){
         body.animate({scrollTop: 0}, '800');
      }else {
         body.animate({scrollTop: secao}, '500');
      }
   }
   
   $('.icone-scroll').click(ScrollSecao);
   
});
```

```css
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

p{
position:absolute;
top:80px;
left:5px;
}

h1{
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:5px;
}

h2{
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:5px;
}
.secao{
position:relative;
height: 100vh;
}

#secao01{
background-color:#0B77C5;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 1px 0;
}

#secao02{
background-color:#fff;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 1px 0;
}

#secao03{
background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 1px 0;
}

#secao04{
background-color:#ccc;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 1px 0;
}
 #secao05{
background-color:#FFF;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 1px 0;
}

.icone-scroll{
position:absolute;
bottom:3em;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:#1a1a1a;
border-radius: 50%;
left:50%;
margin-left:-25px;
cursor:pointer;
}

.scroll{
width:15px;
height:15px;
border-right: 2px solid #fff;
border-bottom : 2px solid #fff;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}

.scroll-next{
transform:rotate(45deg);
margin:14px 0 0 16.5px;
}

.scroll-top{
transform:rotate(225deg);
margin:19px 0 0 17px;
}

.scroll-top + .scroll-top{
top:-15px;
margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="secao01" class="secao"> 
    <h1>
    <center><b>
    
    Nome Completo</b></center> </h1>
    <br>
    <p>
    
     
     RUA, Numero - Bairro<br> Cidade/Estado, Cep<br>
    CELULAR: 11980****** <br>
    E-MAIL: KINHO.***********@GMAIL.COM
      </p>  
      <span class="icone-scroll">
      
      <span class ="scroll-next scroll"> </span>
      </span>
      
      </div>
      
      
      <div id="secao02" class="secao">
      <h3>EDUCAÇÃO E FORMAÇÃO</h3>
      <p> 
      ANÁLISE E DESENVOLVIMENTO DE SISTEMAS - ANHANGUERA
             INÍCIO: JAN/2019 - TÉRMINO: JUN/2021<br>
    
    TÉCNICO EM INFORMÁTICA (PROGRAMAÇÃO) - INSTITUTO TÉCNICO DE BARUERI
              INÍCIO: JUL/2015 - TÉRMINO: JUL/2017<br>
    
    ENSINO MÉDIO COMPLETO (EJA) - E.E. MARIA ALICE CRISSIUMA MESQUITA
              TÉRMINO: DEZ/2014 </p>
      <span class="icone-scroll">
      <span class ="scroll-next scroll"> </span>
      </span>
      
      </div>
      
      
      <div id="secao03" class="secao"> 
      
      <h2>EXPERIÊNCIA PROFISSIONAL </h2>
       <p> 
      HIBERO EXTINTORES, CARAPICUÍBA - SP<br>
     CARGO: PINTOR<br>
     INÍCIO: SET/2011<br>
              TÉRMINO: MAI/2019 </p>
      <span class="icone-scroll">
      <span class ="scroll-next scroll"> </span>
      </span>
      </div>
      
      
      
      <div id="secao04" class="secao"> 
      
      <h2> QUALIFICAÇÕES E ATIVIDADES PROFISSIONAIS</h2>
        
    <p> C#, JAVA, HTML5, ASP.NET, ECLIPSE ANDROID, ORACLE SQL</p>
      <span class="icone-scroll">
      <span class ="scroll-next scroll"> </span>
      </span>
      </div>
      
      <div id="secao05" class="secao"> 
       <h2>OBJETIVO </h2>
      <p> ESTÁGIO/TRAINEE EM DESENVOLVIMENTO DE SISTEMAS </p>
      <span class="icone-scroll">
      <span class ="scroll-top scroll"> </span>
      </span>
      
      </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Resolveu.